# qplot function in R

Tags: r, plot

in R plotting,

```
qplot(age,wage,colour=jobclass,data=training)
```

The 3rd parameter "colour=jobclass" is for coloring the third parameter. I thought this is the third parameter and the plot should be 3-dimensional. But it isn't. Does that mean the function always plot in two dimensions and the third parameter is always used for coloring?

Comment: from coursera http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/19460_cd418196d20548ae9d0f4a8e497f4a31.html ?

Answer (score 4):

`qplot` can only do 2D plots. There is no third positional argument to `qplot`. All arguments must be named after the second one. So your third argument is color because you specified `color=`. You can put any values you want in any order starting at the third parameter as long as you name them. You can tell this because the signature of the function is

```
qplot(x, y = NULL, ..., data, facets = NULL, margins = FALSE, <more stuff>
```

And the `...` consequently means following arguments are no longer positional (as well as indicating that the function will accept other parameters as well).